# Is there any covalent crystals that can be easily synthesized?

Tags: rocks, mineralogy, crystals

I am looking for a kind of crystal that can be artificially made at relatively low temperatures (below 1500 degree Celsius) and relatively quickly (not geological time). The product is ideally monocrystalline, not reactive to oxygen or moisture and not metallic. Ice is excepted.

If such a material exist, I would like to know its name, composition and any other noteworthy properties. If there is anything wrong with the premises of the question, please point it out.

Comment: You mention covalent in the title but not in the question itself. Is that a requirement? Can it be ionic? What is this for? Knowing what you're trying to do might help us. 1500 Celsius is extremely high, above the melting point of many many crystals, yet you mention that it is relatively low. Relative to what?

Comment: You may want to try the chemistry forum

Answer (score 2):

Silicon carbide is covalent and can be synthesized at atmospheric pressure by the Acheson process. Temperatures may actually be somewhat higher than your range but are easily achieved by the process.

1,4 dichlorobenzene (used in moth balls) is a compound that forms crystals at low temperatures. I think the molecules in the crystal are joined only by weak bonds so I don't know if that is what you are after.